# Event triggers don't work on vr that was converted from google cardboard to oculus go/ gear vr

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, oculus

Event triggers don't seem to work on vr experience that was converted from google cardboard to oculus go/ gear vr. They do not seem to react at all.

So on the google cardboard set up the reticle would react to moving over a trigger. Now it does not seem to react at all. I'm not sure if building it for go/gear vr, moves some thing perhaps to the triggers are off?

Comment: It's Good if you add your desired output or more information about the problem and what you have done so for getting better answers.

Comment: Read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Try this video, it explains this issue, and may apply in your case... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNC2NOjNaUc you may need to modify the EventSystem extension you've added (the extra component attached to whatever game-object your using which has EventSystem attached to it)